# how to receive sms in reply of sms sent by plivo API in .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, plivo

i am sending sms on mobile through plivo and then user will reply me by yes or No
to receive sms on my plivo. Now i have make class in c# and put this code

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Nancy;
using RestSharp;
using Plivo.API;

namespace Receive_Sms
{
    public class Program : NancyModule
    {
        public Program()
        {
            Post["/receive_sms"] = x =>
            {
                String from_number = Request.Form["From"]; // Sender's phone number
                String to_number = Request.Form["To"]; // Receiver's phone number
                String text = Request.Form["Text"]; // The text which was received

                // Print the message
                Console.WriteLine("Message received - From: {0}, To: {1}, Text: {2}", from_number, to_number, text);

                return "Message received";
            };
        }
    }
}
```

can i use this code in webservice.asmx if yes how?
how do i test this code?
while creating application in message url
what i write in after server url class name or method name?
 e.g. http://example.com/receive_sms

Answer (score 1):

To receive messages on your Plivo number, you will have to configure the "Message URL" of the Plivo Application attached to that number. Steps to create a Plivo application are [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/receive-an-sms/#create-an-application) and steps to attach that application to your Plivo number are [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/receive-an-sms/#assign-a-plivo-number-to-your-app).

Next, you'll have to host your code publicly so that Plivo can send requests to your .Net application. You could use platforms like Microsoft Azure or Appharbor to host your .Net code. After deployment, use your hosted application URL (like https://yourapp.appharbor.com/receive_sms) to configure the Message URL in your Plivo Application created in the previous step.

"Post["/receive_sms"]" - This line in your code defines the route for you application. The URL that has to be configured as your Message URL would be https://yourapp.domain/receive_sms. More details about routing in Nancy Framework [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes).

To reply to incoming messages, your Message URL should return a Message XML. You can find these instructions [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/reply-to-an-incoming-sms/). More details about Message XML [here](https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/message/).

Comment: i receiver error while receiveing sms 
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Comment: Is your code hosted on the internet and publicly available? Can you check your Plivo debug logs for detailed error?
You could write to support@plivo.com with these details. They'd be able to help you get this resolved.

Comment: i have resolve that to give the message url of my asp.net page rather then service

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> Create .aspx page named reply_to_sms.aspx and paste this code in page load function

```
    String from_number = Request.Form["From"]; // Sender's phone number
    String to_number = Request.Form["To"]; // Receiver's phone number
    String text = Request.Form["Text"]; // The text which was received
```

> After that create a mail function to send these data to email or insert these values in database

```
add application on server by using this link [https://www.plivo.com/docs/sms/getting-started/basic/receive-an-sms/]
```

> Note : you can only check if your page has online link like : abc.com/reply_to_sms.aspx